# CV Axle Stuck on reinstallation (1992 Honda Accord)

Tags: honda, accord, cv-axle

I'm a shop teacher and some students were replacing the passenger side CV axle on a 1992 Honda Accord, EX, Manual drive. They didnt manage to get the shaft in correctly and the locking ring on the end of the cv axle to seat, it is only in as far as the splines with the entire smooth part of the shaft exposed outside the transmission yet we cannot get the shaft in or out now.

I've tried pickle forks, pry bars, slide hammers with cv axle attachments, but it won't budge, if we hammer it out at all, it moves slightly then jams and wont spin anymore, if we hammer it in, it moves back a little, and will allow us to rotate the shaft again.

Hopefully someone has some advice as i'm running out of options and only 1 week left till winter break.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I hate to say it, but it sounds like you're at the point of *force it out*. Not sure how they would have put the axle in incorrectly enough to get it stuck, but *more force* may be your friend here. I've had issues getting the snap ring to initially go in, but once it starts, usually not an issue. Don't know what else to say.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm just not sure how to get more force on it. I cant hammer it from behind as it is recessed in there due to the shape of the transmission, and i've tried prying on it with a 6 foot pry bar and other tools but dont want to risk damaging  the transmission housing if i go any harder.  Slide hammer doesn't feel like it is going to be enough force either.

Comment: If a circlip is used to secure the inner cv axle, slide hammers may work the best as the sudden high force combination may be needed to decouple (shrink) the circlip to force it out of the groove. As the saying goes, "Use the force!" Apply higher acceleration to the slide hammer to create higher impact force.

Comment: I've had the same problem on the exact same vehicle, and unfortunately the answer was more hammers and pry bars until it finally let go. Maybe an air chisel (with a blunt adapter)?